# Cell data relating to userform entries

Tags: vba, excel, counter, data-entry

I hope you can help me as I am stuck at the beginning of my new VBA project and haven't found anything useful on the internet so far.

I am trying to create an excel sheet which varies slightly depending on entries in a userform. 
The thing I am stuck on is the following: 
I need to populate a cell with information that is kinda entered into the userform: 
XXYYZZ - LL

XX being the last two digits of the year (entered as a date into the userform dd.mm.yyyy)
YY being data from a combobox (few possibilities)
ZZ being some kind of counter (haven't figured out how to count this either as the counter should go up depending on how many data sheets have been produced before with the same XXYY)
LL being either numbers or letters entered into a textbox in the userform

Is there any way I could achieve this or is this hopeless?
The only way I could have thought about solving this is with

```
range("A1").value = [yy&combobox1.text&ZZ&" - "&textbox1.text]
```

Is this possible?
Any better ideas?
Still have to figure out a way to count.

Comment: Is the date in the userform a date variable, like from a datepicker?  if so then Right(Year(Me.DTPicker1.Value), 2) would get the two year date.  It's far from hopeless though.  This is what userforms are for, getting data.  You just need to add the values together with an "&" to concatenate them.

Comment: No, I couldn't get DatePicker to work for me. So I just made it that the date has to be entered manually.
So far I had success with getting the UF to get the right data. Now it's just about getting a counter to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do it.  You will still need to determine how you will populate "ZZ" - in this example I have it just set to 1.  My example assumes the value in `TextBox1` is in date format, that `ComboBox1` only has 2 character values and that the value entered in `TextBox2` is always 2 characters.  This code would need to be assigned to a command button on your userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim counter As Long

    counter = 1

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Right(DatePart("yyyy", TextBox1.Value), 2) & ComboBox1.Value & Format(counter, "00") & " - " & TextBox2.Value

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

There are controls you can implement to ensure the data entered is in the format you require for this code to work, but this should get you started at least.

Comment: Great! That helped me heaps. didn't know there was such a function as (datepart(),2). 
Would you have an idea how to make the counter as well? Can Excel remember how often it had that combination before? Since I wasn't planning on saving the sheets.

Comment: I think I will just use a sheet with the UF button on it and a simple excel COUNTIF() function to use as a help for the counter.